# Optimal number of Resque workers for maximum performance

Tags: ruby, mongodb, parallel-processing, resque

I am using Resque for achieving cheap parallelism in my academic research - I split huge tasks   into relatively small independent portions and submit them to Resque. These tasks do some heavy stuff, extensively using both database(MongoDB if that's important) and CPU.

All this works extremely slow - for my relatively small portion of dataset 1000 jobs get created and 14 hours of constant working of 2 workers is enough only for finishing ~800 of them. As you might've already suspected, this speed is more than frustrating.

I have a quad-core processor(Core i5 something, not high-end) and apart from Mongo instance and resque workers nothing gets scheduled on CPU for a considerable period of time.

Now that you know my story, all I am asking is - **how do I squeeze maximum out of this setting**? I believe that 3 workers + 1 mongo instance will quickly fill up all the cores, but at the same time mongo doesn't have to work all the time..

Comment: Start with one worker and keep adding workers until performance starts to go down. There, you have your maximum.

Comment: Well, that of course is a way, a hard way indeed. Isn't there any other? Spending several days on finding out what any other experienced  resquer already knows(probably) doesn't appeal to me somehow :)

Comment: Well, what did you expect? Maybe your jobs are too heavy and you need to move mongo to a dedicated machine. That'll help a little. Also, wny are your jobs so CPU intensive? Do you have a couple of infinite loops in there? :)

Comment: If only I had any opportunity to move anything to a dedicated machine - I would be the happiest person alive :) Well, something of this nature goes on there: array_of_10000_Sets.combination(2){|p1,p2| JaccardCoefficient(p1,p2)}, big sets, expensive intersection and union.

Comment: How do you know the cores are filling up.  What tools are you using to see this?